# Bug in xoring or hex-decoding code

Tags: scala

Could someone suggest what my error is in the code below. I expect that when doing

```
stringXor(hexDecode(s1), hexDecode(s2))
```

with `s1.length == s2.length` and `s1` and `s2` being given hex-encoded strings, the output should be a list of *half* (EDITED) length, but this doesn't hold when playing in the repl.

```
def stringXor(fst: String, snd: String): String = {
  val charInts = (fst.toList, snd.toList).zipped map (_ ^ _)
  charInts.map(_.toChar).toString
}

def hexDecode(s: String): String = {
  hexDec(s.toList).toString
}

def hexDec(s: List[Char]): List[Char] = {
  if (s.length == 0)
    return Nil
  val parts = s.splitAt(2)
  dehex(parts._1) :: hexDec(parts._2)
}

def dehex(cs: List[Char]): Char = {
  (Character.digit(cs.head, 16) * 16 + Character.digit(cs.last, 16)).toChar
}
```

EDIT:
I am trying now with some shorter strings in the repl eg. `s1 = "6558333946494f6e487a6c617645783474653745394f41307143733030356a7331695a3474745437654b58344a42415a6f35"` and `s2 = "5230744346396f6d53776e70425064303039386f5752465a72363944757a3965697847307734364d52426b595532554c7a68"`.

When I do `res0.length` I get `466` and the two strings's lengths are 100.

Comment: Would you be able to supply values of s1 and s2, with the result you expect and what actually occurs?

Comment: @x3ro I have added two strings in the edit above and corrected my mistake on expecting the same length. The lengths should get halved if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hexDecode` function is returning the literal object `String` of your `List[Char]`:

```
scala> hexDecode(s1)
res8: String = List(e, X, 3, 9, F, I, O, n, H, z, l, a, v, E, x, 4, t, e, 7, E, 9, O, A, 0, q, C, s, 0, 0, 5, j, s, 1, i, Z, 4, t, t, T, 7, e, K, X, 4, J, B, A, Z, o, 5)
```

Here's a simple quick fix:

```
  def hexDecode(s: String): String = {
    new String(hexDec(s.toList).toArray)
  }

scala> hexDecode(s1)
res12: String = eX39FIOnHzlavEx4te7E9OA0qCs005js1iZ4ttT7eKX4JBAZo5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly a bit odd. After a bit of playing around with the code myself, I noticed the following:

```
$ hexDecode(s1)
res48: String = List(e, X, 3, 9, F, I, O, n, H, z, l, a, v, E, x, 4, t, e, 7, E, 9, O, A, 0, q, C, s, 0, 0, 5, j, s, 1, i, Z, 4, t, t, T, 7, e, K, X, 4, J, B, A, Z, o, 5)
$ res48.length
res49: Int = 154
```

Wait, that can't be right. And then it hit me :D

```
hexDec(s.toList).toString
```

`toString` generates a string representation, but not what you want. It returns a string including `List(`and a lot of spaces and so on. What you want is `mkString`. And voilá:

```
def hexDecode(s: String): String = {
  hexDec(s.toList).mkString
}
```

Results in:

```
res1: String = eX39FIOnHzlavEx4te7E9OA0qCs005js1iZ4ttT7eKX4JBAZo5
```

---

As a side note, your function naming isn't really great :D Also, you could do the following in `hexDecode` to avoid the extra `hexDec` method:

```
def hexDecode(s: String): String = {
  s.toList.sliding(2,2).flatMap(x => hexDec(x)).mkString
}
```

`sliding` creates a sliding window of size 2 over your list, which is exactly what you do in `hexDec`.